# Mostrar valores false php

Tags: php, operador, lógica

mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un valor que es false en php? Cuando una variable era igual a true, se muestra un 1, pero cuando su valor es false, no aparece nada. ¿Alguna solución?

Código que estoy usando:

```
<?php
    
    
    $p = True;
    $q = True;
    
    echo !$p ;
    
?>
```

Comment: Deseo hacer una tabla de verdad y quiero imprimir el valor de 1 en true (que me muestra un 1) y también en false, donde no aparece nada. Si no puedo mostrar algo en false, ¿Qué puedo hacer para mostrar este valor negado?

Comment: Crea una variable cargable cuando sea true o false... `echo $var? '1' : '0';` aunque como lo dicen, no hay punto de evaluar booleanos de ese modo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-export.php) e cual:

> Imprime o devuelve una representación string de una variable
> analizable

Por ejemplo:

```
var_export(!$p);  # false
var_export($p);   # true
```

Comment: Muchas gracias 